# British residency/citizenship

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship

I am a EEA country national, and I have lived in UK 2 years, as a student. Immediately after those 2 years, I went to work for an international organization that UK is part of (CERN).

Does these 3 years count for the 5 years required to get British citizenship?

Comment: The UK is certainly a member of CERN, and they are also a member of the other CERN, and indeed yet again *another* CERN. And even within the Particle Physics CERN there is a distinction between the research depts and the labs. Unclear, so voting.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you need to be a UK resident for five consecutive years with few interruptions to receive permanent residence, and you can receive UK citizenship one year after receiving permanent residence.

If you stayed in the UK for two years, and then left for a year, you'd have to count starting at zero for "consecutive years" when you return. There are cases were being abroad don't count; working abroad while paid by the UK government might be such a case. Working for CERN most likely isn't unless you were paid by the UK.

Comment: No. There is both Crown Service and Designated Service whereby physical presence in the UK can be excused.  At least one of the CERN entities can be used as designated service, but the OP has not yet clarified. Please edit to correct, many thanks.